# what does yonge mean?

Tags: meaning, archaic-language

> "a proud and very profane yonge man."

This quote is from [here](http://www.history.com/topics/mayflower). What does yonge mean in this context? A search to the [dictionary](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/yonge) came up with:

> Charlotte M(ary). 1823–1901, British novelist, whose works reflect the
>   religious ideals of the Oxford Movement. Her best-known book is The
>   Heir of Redclyffe (1853)

I can't seem to relate a word used to describe a person in the quote to be explained by naming a person (definition as given in the dictionary).

1. What does yonge mean?
2. Could you paraphrase this quote too?

Comment: If you are struggling to understand the dictionary definition for yonge: it is saying that the only "yonge" it has ever heard of is someone's name, i.e. *Charlotte M Yonge*. You'll find something similar if you search for [Shakespeare](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/shakespeare). I believe this is not a very good way to write a dictionary - someone's name is not a word. If they really *have* to put it in, it should call it a *proper noun* not just a *noun*.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

This is 17th century English, a time when spelling was slightly different and, above all, less standardized than today.   "Transcribed" in modern English you'd get:

> "a proud and very profane young man."

Comment: On the linked page, the quote is actually set off in quotation marks as a sign that it was a "direct" quote which wasn't fully translated.

Comment: Heh heh. Spell checkers in those days were very slow. And did not get updated very often.

Answer (score -1):

1. Swiss term for a female who can yodel through a valve, or more so a / her flange. YO(del)nge / yo(fla)NGE.
2. Someone who has perfected all instrumentation technique in a brass ensemble.
3. Onomatopoeia of the audible sound made by a brass instrument. i.e, flugelhorn, tuba, trombone etc.,
4. Simile. 'Oom-pah'

Comment: Hello,  Please note that this is a very old question, and your answer doesn't take into account the context.  As such I think your answer is incorrect.  Please take a look at some more recent and unanswered questions, and make sure that you use all the context from the body of the question.